# Render output panel based on page number

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, rendered

Is it possible to render an output panel based on the page it's being displayed on in a visual force pdf?

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered = "counter(page) == 3">
```

Comment: I think you can do it on CSS

Answer (score 0):

As @ytiq mentioned, you can do it with CSS but use page media and CSS `counter` function as shown on the [Help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324733&type=1).

As far as I know, there is no page counter on Visualforce functions or controller, so unless you develop something custom, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: I have a line in my code, "<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;"> ". If i was able to display the header after this line only if a page break occurs, then this would solve my issue. Do you know is this possible?

Comment: It might be possible to hook a style class to a div and use the page media and counter as mentioned in the Help article.